# Why loading a video with Flash (AS3) changes the pixel colors a bit?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors

I have a video (MP4) I load using Flash (AS3).
I load the video locally using NetStream object,
and when I sample the pixels - they are a bit 'off'.

To test this - I prepared a video with 100 frames of only red pixels (all the pixels are 0xFF0000).

When I load this video using flash's NetStream class,
and then use 'getPixel' to test the pixel color of a frame shown,
I get that the pixel color is:

- R = 255
- G = 12
- B = 0

.

Why is the 'green' value not 0 ??

Also, when I load a video that contains only green frames,
the value of the pixel after Flash loaded it is :

- R = 0
- G = 232
- B = 0

.

Only the blue video frame are correct (0,0,255).

Why is this ? can it be that flash is decoded the video and performing some processing on it that changes the colors ?

I need the colors to be exact, because I sample different pixels to detect stuff, and I need the colors to be shown exactly like they really are in the video !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the same person [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?375745-Why-loading-a-video-with-Flash-%28AS3%29-changes-the-pixel-colors-a-bit&p=2648136)? I would second the answer provided by **bwhiting**:

> This will be the encoding process not the readback in flash. I have
>   done many tests with this and the best solution (if you are embedding
>   data in video pixels, is to use thresholds.. as they values should not
>   be radically out but only marginally.. but again this will change
>   based on how compressed the clip is - more compression = less accurate
>   colour info)

It has to relate to a loss while you encoded the red or green video.

Comment: but how come when I open the video using Media Player - and grab the image - the values are correct ?
If I open it with VLC - the values are incorrect.
It is almost as if - each decoder decides to decode the values differently (and Flash along with them)